Visual Studio Code Sync Problems
When i activate Sync on VS Code it installs some old Extention i dont want to have anymore. When i set them to "dont sync" and uninstall them, that Moment i enable the Sync on a new PC/Installation it loads all Extenstions again.
Can i delete them or "reset" my Sync Account?
modified the settings.json

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and see [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. If I could suggest one: "How do I get VSCode Sync to stop installing an extension I don't want anymore?"

I found the Solution.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_restoring-data
You can clear the Data in the Cloud.
